# laravel simple whereIn query return lots of incorrect rows

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

for some reason the same query is running differently in mysql and laravel

table structure

```
field: codoriginal => varchar 191 => nullable
index: codoriginal => non_unique 1 | seq_in_index 1 | collation A | cardinality 7449
```

mysql query => took 320 ms and returns **92 rows**

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE codoriginal IN (
  ...
  'string', // list with 2500 strings
  ...
);
```

laravel query => took 42 seconds and returns **34000 rows**

```
$allKeys = [...]; // list with 2500 strings
$q = MyModel::whereIn('codoriginal', $allKeys)->get();
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: check `dd( MyModel::whereIn('codoriginal', $allKeys)->toSql())` in case there are any global scopes added that might cause unexpected side-effects

Comment: solved by adding `array_filter()` to strings array so it removes empty elements